# Table break in css

Tags: html, css, html-table, frontend, border

When a page is saved as pdf, the table breaks but the bottom border of table on first page and top border of table on second page is not displayed.

I want to get border to bottom and top side of table when it breaks on different pages and saved as pdf.

Comment: can you please add a code or screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.page-break-next-row {
  border-left-color: white;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-top-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="page-break">
    <td class="page-break">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="page-break-next-row">
    <td class="page-break-next-row"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```